# Laravel 4 - Model relations for Posts with multiple Image Uploads

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, pivot-table

How would you set this up?

**Each Post has one Image (which can have a title/caption/etc) and each Image has multiple Uploads (different image sizes).**

I've got a working setup for this going right now using pivot tables and model relations but it's not very pretty to query the data with these uploads... I just wanted to take a step back for a moment here and ask how another person out there would approach this?

I want to use eloquent to simply grab the Post Object with all of it's associated images and their uploads included.

Here's a screenshot of my full current db schema in case you're interested:

[image]

Comment: Why do you need a pivot table? Can a particular upload be associated with multiple images?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins No, but a particular image can have multiple uploads... I hadn't considered just using the image_id directly in the uploads table... I'm gonna explore that here. Thanks

Comment: Use `hasMany` and `hasMany`. There is no need for pivot table linking `Image` and `Uploads` in your case. Then you can make the most of the framework with `hasManyThrough` for `Post` - `Uploads`.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk_deczo_ oh wow, I hadn't even noticed `hasManyThrough` there in the eloquent docs. This is great, thank you.

Comment: @inrgb Check this http://softonsofa.com/ , you can find some sensible examples that can help you start.